# Office 365 DirSync Using Trial Domain

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365

I've signed up for an Office 365 trial and have set up a test lab server functioning as a local DC with a fictitious domain -- basically the idea was that I wanted to set up a test domain/lab that's separate from our production environment in order to test drive some office 365 features, particularly Directory Sync, and so I haven't added nor verified an additional domain in Office 365 other than the default one provided (with .onmicrosoft.com at the end) when initially signing up.

Now when I look to run the dirsync tool and get up to the part where it asks me to sign in with credentials for the Office 365 online account/tenant, after hitting next I receive the error message:

"An error occurred.  Error Code: 15.  Error Description: Identity synchronization is not yet activated for this company.  To activate identity synchronization, click the Activate button on the Identity synchronization page in your Admin Portal..."

Now I go to the admin portal and then go to Users>Active users and then click "Set Up" for Active directory synchronization.  In order to activate the Active Directory Synchronization, it mentions that I must add and verify a domain before being able to activate Active Directory Synchronization.

Since I basically don't have a domain I can add as a test with proper DNS records, etc... is there any way around this that will allow me to use the provided onmicrosoft.com domain as part of the trial to test out dirsync?

Comment: I doubt it. You could try creating a subdomain of your public hosted domain, like "test.<yourdomain>.com" and see if it will let you add and verify that subdomain in Office 365. On the other hand, my favorite DNS host only charges $15 for a *year* of DNS hosting, so just register a throwaway domain for this.

Comment: Thanks Todd, I was thinking of doing that as well as I'm sure it will come in useful for other testing/tasks.  Just curious, what DNS/domain provider is it that you use that charges $15/yr?

Comment: The one you can find on Google.  Pretty much anyone will do you a .co.uk or .com for very very little money.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be done, you can't enable DirSync on "onmicrosofton.com", you'll have to add your own domain first, there is no workaround through that.

If you really need to test DirSync, buying a domain name is your only option, beware that not all domain name providers support creating records for Office 365, so you must buy from one of the Office 365 approved list mentioned in the Microsoft support link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Service-limitations-when-your-hosting-provider-does-not-support-SRV-CNAME-TXT-or-redirection-7ae9a655-041d-4724-aa92-60392ee390c2

Some of those providers have a very nice integration with Office 365, where you provide the username and password for the domain setup wizard and it'll create the needed records without user input.

Comment: ++++ buy a new domain with a service where you can edit txt records!

Comment: Today with Azure AD COnnect, if you sync a domain from on premise, lets say something.local then the accounts will sync they will just be given the .onmicrosoft.com suffix.